# Error: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Field 'stu_id' doesn't have a default value

Tags: sql, jdbc

I'm new to JDBC and SQL and I have this program but when I run it, I get the following error:

```
java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Field 'stu_id' doesn't have a default value.
```

I have tried manipulating the line

```
pst = con.prepareStatement("insert into student(first_name,last_name,address) values  (?,?,?)");
```

by adding a 4th question mark in values, and by adding stu_id in insert into student(). However, they have only given other errors. I don't know what to do?

```
package java11;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class PreparedExample {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Connection con=null;
    PreparedStatement pst=null;
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/world","root","Sree7rama3**");
        pst = con.prepareStatement("insert into student(first_name,last_name,address) values (?,?,?)");

        for(int i=1;i<=20;i++){
            //pst.setInt(1, i);
            pst.setString(1, "Hello-"+i);
            pst.setString(2, "World-"+i);
            pst.setString(3,"HYD-"+i);
            pst.addBatch();
        }
        pst.executeBatch();

        System.out.println("Update is successful!");
    }catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("There are some SQL errors!");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Driver class is not attached to this project!");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        try {
            pst.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            con.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: The table structure would be helpful

Comment: Table structure: First column (stu_id (primary key)), second column (first_name), third_column(last_name), fourth column (address)

Comment: when you added stu_id to your insert statement what errors did you get

Comment: java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like when you added stu_id to you statement presumably you added this line

```
pst.setInt(1, i);
```

and you had these lines

```
pst.setString(1, "Hello-"+i);
pst.setString(2, "World-"+i);
pst.setString(3,"HYD-"+i);
```

So you were overwriting the first parameter (both 1).

try

```
pst = con.prepareStatement("insert into student(stu_id,first_name,last_name,address) values (?,?,?,?)");



pst.setInt(1, i);
pst.setString(2, "Hello-"+i);
pst.setString(3, "World-"+i);
pst.setString(4,"HYD-"+i);
```

Comment: It added the rows to my table, but I'm getting the error java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Duplicate entry '20'for key 'PRIMARY'

Comment: Well the values for your primay key have to be unique, so if you run this more than once you will be trying to insert duplicate values for stu_id. (i your incrementer)

Comment: I don't know what database you are using but perhaps make stu_id an auto incremented field